# Trigger to check duplicate value in one table

Tags: triggers

I have a database for football system with a table `match`:

- `Match_ID int` primary key
- `Home_ID int` (foreign key to table `Clubs`)
- `Visitor_ID int` (foreign key to table `Clubs`)

I have written a trigger to check and I succeeded for create but not for update.

```
CREATE TABLE Clubs
(
    Club_ID int,
    Name varchar2(100),
    Stadium varchar2(100),
    League_ID int,
    primary key(Club_ID),
    foreign key(League_ID) references Leagues(League_ID)
)

CREATE TABLE Matches
(
    Match_ID int,
    Home_ID int,
    Visitor_ID int,
    Official_ID int,
    DateMatch date,

    primary key(Match_ID),
    foreign key(Home_ID) references Clubs(Club_ID),
    foreign key(Visitor_ID) references Clubs(Club_ID),
    foreign key(Official_ID) references Officials(Official_ID)
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Check_Duplicate
before insert or update on Matches
FOR each ROW
   declare v_dup number;
begin
    select count(Match_ID) INTO v_dup 
    from Matches 
    where :NEW.Home_ID =:NEW.Visitor_ID;

    if v_dup > 0 then
        Raise_Application_Error (-20100, 'This team already exists. The insert is cancelled.');
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.